# SQL CASE Statement Not Working Correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a view in SQL Server 2008 with several columns that are expressions of one column divided by another.  I have to account for the divisor being 0, so I use a CASE statement.  Here is an example of one:

```
CASE SUM(dbo.GameStats.BringBacksAttempted) 
  WHEN 0 THEN 
    0 
  ELSE 
    SUM(dbo.GameStats.BringBacks) / SUM(dbo.GameStats.BringBacksAttempted) 
END
```

Even when SUM(BringBacksAttempted) and SUM(BringBacks) are not 0, the statement is always 0.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What data type is BringBacksAttempted and BringBacks?
If both are int and the result comes to be a fraction, you will only see integer part of it.

e.g. 100 / 250 will return 0.
Whereas, `CAST(100 as Decimal) / 250` will return 0.40000

Use a CAST or CONVERT on one of the fields.

Comment: I meant multiply either the top or the bottm of the division by 1.0, not the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
CASE 
  WHEN SUM(dbo.GameStats.BringBacksAttempted) = 0 THEN 
    0 
  ELSE 
    SUM(dbo.GameStats.BringBacks) / SUM(dbo.GameStats.BringBacksAttempted) 
END
```